# Bootstrap Gridsystem col is not Working Properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, col

Here is my code:

I've tried change container class to container-fluid also resize the page.

> ```
> <div class="container">
>     <div class="row">
>         <!--Product: banana split-->
>         <div class="col">
>             <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
>                 <img class="card-img-top" src="img/banana-split.png" alt="Banana Split Image">
>                 <div class="card-block">
>                     <h4 class="card-title">Banana Split</h4>
>                     <p class="card-text">Price: 5$</p>
>                     <a href="#" data-name="banana-split" data-price="5" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="col">
>             <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
>                 <img class="card-img-top" src="img/bengala-doce.png" alt="Bengala Doce Image">
>                 <div class="card-block">
>                     <h4 class="card-title">Doce Natalino</h4>
>                     <p class="card-text">Price: 2$</p>
>                     <a href="#" data-name="doce-natalino" data price="3" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

The problem is the second col is not being placed side by side. It's being placed below each other.
I looked up on the console and there's not any warning.

Others stuff like bootstrap buttons is working fine.

Comment: would you like to post a image of your output please. cz the question is not so clear to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set your column classes depending on screen sizes you are viewing. This way, making 2 columns on mediums screen sizes, and on column in small screens using `col-md-6 col-sm-12`

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Product: banana split-->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/banana-split.png" alt="Banana Split Image">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Banana Split</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Price: 5$</p>
                        <a href="#" data-name="banana-split" data-price="5" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/bengala-doce.png" alt="Bengala Doce Image">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Doce Natalino</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Price: 2$</p>
                        <a href="#" data-name="doce-natalino" data price="3" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```